# different behavior on same code in different installation of r

Tags: r

When I run following code:

```
library(turboEM)
library(SparseM)
library(quantreg)
library(numDeriv)
library(foreach)
library(parallel) 
libraary(iterators)
library(doParallel)
library(logbin)
library(glm2)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

data(heart)
head(heart)
start.p <- sum(data1$deaths) / sum(data1$patients)

fit.glm <- glm(cbind(deaths, patients-deaths) ~ factor(age) + factor(severity) +

factor(onset) + factor(region), family = binomial(log),
start = c(log(start.p), -rep(1e-4, 8)), data = data1,trace = TRUE, maxit = 100)

fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), trace = 1,data=data1)
summary(fit.logbin)

# Speed up convergence by using single EM algorithm
fit.logbin.em <- update(fit.logbin, method = "em")
summary(fit.logbin.em)

# Speed up convergence by using acceleration methods
fit.logbin.acc <- update(fit.logbin, accelerate = "squarem")
summary(fit.logbin.acc)
fit.logbin.em.acc <- update(fit.logbin.em, accelerate = "squarem")
summary(fit.logbin.em.acc)

sink("C:\\Users\\ak.biglarian\\Desktop\\MrsZooghi\\Out.logbin.txt")
summary(fit.logbin.em)
sink()
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
logbin(formula = formula(fit.glm), data = heart, method = "em", 
trace = 1)
```

on different installations of R-project, I get different results on same code!

In one installation I get the code running pretty good but in another installation I get following errors:

```
> fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), trace = 1,data=data1)
Error in logbin(formula(fit.glm), trace = 1, data = data1) : 
     unused argument (data = data1)
```

or

```
> logbin(formula = formula(fit.glm), data = heart, method = "em", 
+     trace = 1)
Error in logbin(formula = formula(fit.glm), data = heart, method = "em",  : 
  unused arguments (formula = formula(fit.glm), data = heart, method = "em")
```

What is the reason? And how shall I fix this?

Comment: Are all the package versions the same?

Comment: @tkerwin How shall I check the versions?

Comment: Try `packageVersion("logbin")` on each of your installations to check they are the same. If not, update all to the latest version: `install.packages("logbin")`.

If this doesn't solve your problem, it might be that you have (unintentionally?) named another object or function `logbin`. Try `find("logbin")` and if anything other than `package:logbin` appears, you'll need to remove the conflicting objects.